# UNIX права: что значит исполнение?

Tags: unix

Есть `чтение (4)`, `запись (2)` и `исполнение (1)`.
Что значит `исполнение`? 
Объясните простыми словами и примером.

Comment: Исполнить == выполнить == запустить == стартовать команды в скрипте... Вроде слово то русское...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**для файла** это означает, что его можно **выполнить**, обратившись к нему:

- либо по имени, поместив его в один из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной окружения `PATH` (или дополнив значение этой переменной путём к текущему местоположению этого файла)
- либо указав полный путь к файлу

понятно, что **выполнить** файл можно, только если он:

- либо является скриптом и в первой строке у него указан корректный «[shebang](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix))»
- либо является программой (скомпилированной под набор инструкций вашего процессора) **и** операционной системе «известно», как его загрузить в память и в какую точку передать управление

---

**для каталога** это означает, что можно прочитать не только имена файлов/каталогов, находящихся внутри данного каталога, **но и** их атрибуты (принадлежность, права доступа, время создания/модификации). пример:

создаём тестовый каталог, в нём создаём файл и ещё один каталог:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/file
$ mkdir test/dir
```

сейчас мы видим атрибуты содержимого каталога `test`:

```
$ ls -l test
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr  1 23:39 dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    0 Apr  1 23:38 file
```

а если уберём бит исполнимости с каталога `test`:

```
$ chmod -x test
```

то увидим только имена содержащихся в нём файлов/каталогов:

```
$ ls -l test
ls: cannot access test/dir: Permission denied
ls: cannot access test/file: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? dir
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? file
```

и не сможем «заглянуть глубже», например, посмотреть содержимое каталога `test/dir`:

```
$ ls -l test/dir
ls: cannot access test/dir: Permission denied
```