# Ошибка при запуске tomcat: cannot run program in directory, отказано в доступе

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

При запуске SpringMVC проекта выбрасывает такую ошибку:

```
Error running Tomcat 8.0.331:  
Cannot run program "/home/vitaly/Загрузки/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/bin/catalina.sh" (in directory "/home/vitaly/Загрузки/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/bin"):  
error=13, Отказано в доступе
```

*Первый раз использую tomcat!*

**Подскажите, в чем проблема.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вероятно, у файла `/home/vitaly/Загрузки/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/bin/catalina.sh` отсутствуют [права на исполнение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/509036/178576).

попробуйте их добавить:

```
$ chmod +x /home/vitaly/Загрузки/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/bin/catalina.sh
```